# meta_query compare='!=' with multiple custom fields

Tags: meta-query

a post has the following custom fields:

```
'my_custom_field' => 1
'my_custom_field' => 2
'my_custom_field' => 3
```

I now want to query all posts that do NOT contain the value 2 for 'my_custom_field'. I'm trying this:

```
$args = Array('posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'my_custom_field',
        'value' => 2,
        'compare' => '!='
      )
    )
  );
```

However, this is still returning my sample post, as my sample post has a field of 'my_custom_field' with a value other than 2 (1 and 3). I somehow need to change my query to say "Exclude posts that have at least one field of 'my_custom_field' with the value of 2".

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, your query currently asks for posts that have a meta key that isn't 2, which is true of your post, because it has a 1 and a 3

Comment: Can you clarify what your custom field is intended to do? Its possible that a custom taxonomy may be more appropriate here

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yeah, the query does what it says, but I need to change the query. I want the query to be "Find posts where none of the values are 2."

As for what I'm trying to do. The custom fields are a one-way relation, similar to categories. The field is called "has_category" and a value would be the post_id of the specific category. So basically I want to query all posts which are not in category '2'.

Comment: That doesn't explain **why** you want this, what is the point of the `has_category` field? ( I don't mean what should it do, I mean why does it need to do it? This question sounds like an XY problem, are you trying to implement related posts/upselling?

Comment: I am pretty sure I could make this work, and pretty sure it would take a filter to do it, but I am also wondering if this is just the wrong approach altogether. Please explain the _why_.

Comment: Assume posts are products. `has_category` is basically a list of features. Features are regular Wordpress pages (can't change that). I can easily list all the features by going through all the values for `has_category`. Now in return I want the feature page to also show all products that possess this feature. This is a simple WP_Query (Get all posts where the `has_category` has the value of the current ID. Now there's special case where I need all products that have feature x, but don't have feature y.

Comment: It might very well be, that this approach is not the right one. If so, please tell me what is. However, this is an existing project and I can't really change the whole structure from the ground up. For this particular situation I like the subquery apporach (answer below) - as I can't change the entire thing. Another (ugly) workaround could be to query all posts and then filter out the ones I don't want using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might require writing custom sql with a subquery:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE ID NOT IN (
      SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
      WHERE meta_key = 'my_custom_field' and meta_value = 2
    )
");
```

then just iterate through the results as [described here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).

Comment: You wrapped `meta_value` in string quotes, but other than that it works perfectly, thanks! I'll upvote you as soon as I have the required reputation ;)

Comment: @Etienne I removed the quotes on meta_value.

Comment: @Etienne, I wrote this only because you are new here, if this answer works for you, you should mark it as accepted (there's no required reputation for that), otherwise question is seen as 'unanswered' where it seems isn't so.

Answer (score 0):

As **@TomJNowell** and **@s_ha_dum** says you in comments, in your case probably a custom taxonomy is better than custom fields, because is very easy to get a post that has not a taxonomy term.

That said, I understand that if you have a lot of code alreadt wrote, or you are working with third party code, moving to custom taxonomy can be hard / not possible.

Aswer provided by **@elleeott** works, however is not flexible, because you can't change posts per page, meta value, etc..

I'll provide you a similar solution, but a bit more flexible and you can *fine tune* it to fit your needs.

Essentially is just a class that extend `WP_Query` and apply filters to request to perform a what you want

```
class MyMetaQuery extends WP_Query {

   protected $do_posts_request_filter = TRUE;

   function get_posts() {
     $this->query_vars['suppress_filters'] = FALSE; // force do filters
     add_action( 'posts_request', array( $this, 'filter_request' ), 999 );
     parent::get_posts();
     $this->do_posts_request_filter = FALSE; // run only once
   }

   /* build the sql request */
   function filter_request( $request ) {
      if ( ! $this->do_posts_request_filter ) return $request;
      $q = $this->get('meta_query');
      if ( empty($q) || ! is_array($q) || ! isset($q[0]['key']) ) return $request;
      global $wpdb;
      $k = $q[0]['key'];
      $v = isset( $q[0]['value'] ) ? $q[0]['value'] : '';
      if ( is_array( $v ) ) $v = implode( ',', $v );
      $mcompare = isset( $q[0]['compare'] ) ? $q[0]['compare'] : 'IN';
      if ( ! in_array( $mcompare, array('IN', 'NOT IN', '=', '!=') ) ) {
        $mcompare = 'IN';
      }
      if ( $mcompare === '!=' ) $mcompare = 'NOT IN';
      if ( $mcompare === '=' ) $mcompare = 'IN';
      $ppage = $this->get('posts_per_page') ? : get_option('posts_per_page');
      $limit = $wpdb->prepare(' LIMIT %d', $ppage);
      if ( substr_count( $limit, '-1' )  ) $limit = '';
      if ( $limit && $this->get('nopaging') ) $limit = '';
      $type_compare = 'IN';
      $type = $this->get('post_type') ? : 'post';
      if ( is_array( $type ) ) $type = implode(',', $type );
      if ( $type === 'any' ) {
        $type_compare = 'NOT IN';
        $status = '-1';
      }
      $status_compare = 'IN';
      $status = $this->get('post_status') ? : 'publish';
      if ( is_array($status) ) $type = implode(',', $status);
      if ( $status === 'any' ) {
        $status_compare = 'NOT IN';
        $status = '-1';
      }
      $query = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        WHERE post_type $type_compare (%s)
        AND post_status $status_compare (%s)
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = %s
        AND ID NOT IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
          WHERE meta_key = %s and CAST(meta_value AS CHAR) $mcompare (%s)
        )
      ";
      return $wpdb->prepare( $query, $type, $status, $k, $k, $v ) . $limit;
   }

}
```

After that, instead of using `WP_Query` you have to use `MyMetaQuery` class:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array( 'key' => 'my_custom_field', 'value' => 2, 'compare' => '!=' )
  )
);

$query = new MyMetaQuery( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); 
    // do what you want here
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Note thats the only params the custom class accepts are:

- `'post_type'`, can be a single types, a comma-separed string or an
  array of types or *'any'*
- `'post_status'` can be a single status, a comma-separed string or an
  array of statuses or *'any'*
- `'posts_per_page'` can be a posistive number or *'-1'*
- `'nopaging'` can be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Set to TRUE will return all posts overriding 'posts_per_page'
- `'meta_query'` accepts a multidimensional array, just like `WP_Query`. Note that you can only pass one query array, any additional query will be ignored. The query array accepts as array keys: `'key'`, `'value'` and `'compare'`. `'value'` can be a single value, a comma-separed string or an array of values. `'compare'` can be *'IN'*, *'NOT IN'*, *'='* and *'!='*

If you need other arguments (category, tags, taxonomies, date, etc) you must extend the class features or, more probably, use another approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. This is indeed the most flexible approach. In this case I've already implemented @elleeott 's code and extended it by a couple other WHERE clauses to exclude unpublished posts, etc. Works perfectly for this situation.

I will keep your solution in mind, I'm pretty sure I might use it in the future. Thanks a lot. I will also definitely look into custom taxonomy.

I'll upvote as soon as I have the required reputation.

Comment: @Etienne essentially my answer is just an extension of @elleeott's code too. The problems I see there are: **(1)** little flexibility **(2)** the fact that to use template tags (`the_title` and such) for retrieved posts you have to `setup_postdata($post)` or `apply_filters` everytime **(3)** possible issues with some plugins, in fact what you get are *raw* objects, where `WP_Query` returns `WP_Posts` objects **(3)** last, but not least, using that code you retrieve all the posts that have no `'my_custom_field'` at all, where `WP_Query` with `'meta_query'` doesn't work like so.